# Filter frequency using python

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, fft, frequency

I am new to Python so please pardon me if this question is very basic.

I have Accelerometer Vector Magnitude (acc_VM) signal with sampling frequency of 100Hz. I have to find the Fourier transform of this signal and find the fundamental frequency between range Df.

Df is the family of frequencies corresponding to walking. Here we use Df = [1.2, 4]Hz. How can I choose the frequency range Df = [1.2, 4]Hz using python should I implement filters OR is combFunction() the correct code ?

```
def combFunction(n):
    combSignal = []
    for element in n:
        if element>1.2 and element<4 :
            combSignal.append(element)
        else:
            combSignal.append(0)
    return np.maximum(combSignal)

def hann(total_data):
    hann_array = np.zeros(total_data)
    for i in range(total_data):
        hann_array[i] = 0.5 - 0.5 * np.cos((2 * np.pi * i)/(total_data - 1))
    return hann_array

def calculate_FT(x):
    hann_weight = hann(len(x))
    x_multiplied_hann = x * hann_weight
    X = np.abs(np.fft.rfft(x_multiplied_hann))
         combSignal = combFunction(X)

calculate_FT(acc_VM)
```

Comment: Thanks bud, Df has been implemented in the code 
''''''

Answer (score 0):

The FFT does not return frequencies, but rather an array of amplitudes for a fixed set of evenly spaced frequencies.
As a result your `combFunction`, as implemented, would pick the components which have a spectrum amplitude between 1.2 and 4.

To be able to select frequencies, you would need the corresponding array of those evenly spaced frequencies, which you can get
from [`np.fft.rfftfreq`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfftfreq.html).
Note that you will need the sampling rate (and if your data isn't uniformly sampled, you will need to resample it).
In the code that follows I'll use the variable `sampling_rate` for that. Then the frequencies will be given by:

```
freqs = np.fft.rfftfreq(len(data), sampling_rate)
```

Now let's extract the array indices corresponding to those frequencies that are within the frequency band of interest:

```
in_band = np.where([f >= 1.2 and f <= 4 for f in freqs])[0]
```

Then you may get the location within this band where the original spectrum `X` has a peak:

```
peak_location = np.argmax(X[in_band])
```

which gives you a peak spectrum amplitude `X[in_band[peak_location]]` at a frequency `f[in_band[peak_location]]`.
Putting it all together should give you something like the following:

```
def find_peak_in_frequency_range(X, freqs, fmin, fmax):
  in_band = np.where([f >= fmin and f <= fmax for f in freqs])[0]
  peak_location = np.argmax(X[in_band])
  return f[in_band[peak_location]], X[in_band[peak_location]]

def calculate_FT(x, sampling_rage):
  hann_weight = hann(len(x))
  x_multiplied_hann = x * hann_weight
  X = np.abs(np.fft.rfft(x_multiplied_hann))
  freqs = np.fft.rfftfreq(len(x), sampling_rate)
  peakFreq,peakAmp = find_peak_in_frequency_range(X, freqs, 1.2, 4)
```

Note that you may get better results by using a [spectrum estimation method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density_estimation) such as [`scipy.signal.welch`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.welch.html) instead of simply taking the FFT.

For sake of illustration, I've ran the above on a [sample data set](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/User+Identification+From+Walking+Activity) (file `1.csv` with some resampling):

[image: Peak finding on a sample data set]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation . I appreciate your efforts and thank you again.